# Wro4j enable/disable cache dyanamically

Tags: caching, dynamic, requesthandler, wro4j

I would like to configure Wro4j in such a way that it should dynamically enable/disable cache based on the properties file (not wro.properties)

is implementing a custom RequestHandeler good ideal? 
Please let me know if there is any possible way to do it.

Moreover, It would be really great if i can do that based on request parameter:

eg: calling the URL /wro/main.css?disableCache=true should give me the main.css generated by Wro4j (with compete wro4j life cycle) and not from the cache.

Note: I am using spring MVC.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was also posted on the wro4j [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wro4j/cToFMUHCNAQ):

You could achieve this with a custom [RequestHandler](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/RequestHandler). The handler would accept request having disableCache request param set to true and the implementation would invalidate the cache for the requested group: cacheStrategy.put(cacheKey, null);

But before using the above approach, I would suggest a simpler one:

```
resourceWatcherUpdatePeriod=5
resourceWatcherAsync=true
```

The above two [configuration properties](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/ConfigurationOptions) should ensure that you get the most recent result after 5 seconds. The wro4j would check for you if there are any changed resources and will process them asynchronously without affecting your development cycle.

**UPDATE**

An example implementing the custom request handler which invalidates the requested group when the disableCache parameter is provided is available [here](https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j-examples/tree/master/custom-request-handlers).

Comment: Replied on wro4j mailing list too. I am looking for something like calling /wro/main.css?disableCache=false should give me result from cache and /wro/main.css?disableCache=true should give me result by freshly generated wro4j life cycle. Moreover I already have resourceWatcherUpdatePeriod configured.
It would be really great if you can give me more inside of requestHander.Any example would be really helpful.

Comment: The wro.properties way worked for me. This answer deserves more upvotes

Comment: Ah, you are the wro4j dev :) Good job then